# Swift: "any generic" in function causes "_ErrorCodeProtocol has no member" error

Tags: swift, generics, any

Swift 5.8 using 'any generic' causes strange error (_ErrorCodeProtocol)

Hello! In my Pet project I want to reduce layout code for UIKit (I'm using programmatic UI layout). The idea is to make enum for most used cases in my pet like:

```
// view is a view controller's view
let searchArea = UIView()
view.addSubview(searchArea)
searchArea.applyConstraints(
   .alignTopWithTop(of: guide),
   .alignLeadingWithLeading(of: view),
   .alignTrailingWithTrailing(of: view),
   .alignHeight(with: view, mult: 0.1)
)
```

I really like it much more than:

```
let searchArea = UIView()
view.addSubview(searchArea)
object.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  searchArea.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
  searchArea.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
  searchArea.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
  searchArea.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0)
])
```

Because UIViews should be aligned to other UIView childs as well as UIViewController safe Area (UILayoutGuide) I implemented this using generics:

```
protocol UISnapable {
    var leadingAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor { get }
    // Here are other anchors that UIView and UILayoutGuide have at the same time
    var centerYAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }
}


extension UIView: UISnapable {}
extension UILayoutGuide: UISnapable {}

enum Constraints<T: UISnapable> {
    case alignTopWithTop(of: T, const: CGFloat = 0)
    // Other align cases here
    case setAspectWidth(ratio: CGFloat)
}


func applyConstraints(object: inout UIView, constraints: any UISnapable...) {
    object.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        // Transforming input variadic to constraints
        constraints.map {
            switch $0 {
            case .alignTopWithTop(of: let of, const: let const):
                return object.topAnchor.constraint(
                    equalTo: of.topAnchor,
                    constant: const
                )
            // Other align cases here
            case .setAspectWidth(ratio: let ratio):
                return object.heightAnchor.constraint(
                    equalTo: object.widthAnchor,
                    multiplier: ratio
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

I use "any" keyword for generic UISnapable as it's was recently introduced in Swift for such cases.

But unfortunately, I get error "Type _ErrorCodeProtocol has no member alignTopWithTop"

What I am doing wrong? I dunno how _ErrorCodeProtocol is connected to my generic case.

I've checked source of _ErrorCodeProtocol and it lead to Foundation. But I didn't find its declaration somewhere in foundation. Also I didn't find information on it in Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=_ErrorCodeProtocol&type=Documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a list of UISnapable, but you mean to pass a list of Constraints. In this case you're putting `any` in the wrong place.

What I believe you mean is this:

```
// Constraints are not generic, but they can hold any UISnapable in some cases
enum Constraints {
    // Use `any UISnapable` rather than T
    case alignTopWithTop(of: any UISnapable, const: CGFloat = 0)
    // Other align cases here
    case setAspectWidth(ratio: CGFloat)
}
```

And then the method is (note that the `inout` here is unnecessary; UIView is a reference type):

```
func applyConstraints(object: inout UIView, constraints: Constraints...) {
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As for the error, the compiler is just getting confused because you're trying to `switch` on a non-enum (`$0` here is `any UISnapable`). The error is not particularly helpful, and is not related to the underlying problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply, I changed my code as you describer, but, unfortunately, error has not gone. It remains the same.

Comment: I've noticed one strange thing. Usually when you put switch covering not all enum cases, Xcode tells you that switch must be exhaustive and offers to add all cases. But here, when I switch Constraints, it only tells that default should be added. May be something wrong with enum, I'll try finding it out.

Comment: I implemented your idea, but much simplified (a test case - protocol and enum contain only 2 elements). It compiles okay.. hmm, may be I should add some code (to make it like in the first post) until XCode tells the error.

Comment: The problem is because $0 having <<error type>>. Trying to find out why.

Comment: Yes, problem is solved. The problem was because of wrong argument type for closure.  I didn't notice that Rob told to replace "constraints: any UISnapable" with "constraints: Constraints". That completely solved the problem.